# Why we need JPA Provider

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I know  JPA is a specification of the persistence standard, we can't use JPA without any provider, but I don't understand what differences are between jpa providers.
I looked up several examples of

- hibernate jpa provider
- eclipselink jpa provider

the code looks almost the same to me.

What differences are between the jpa providers, please?

Comment: Please, add the links with the code that you are read

Comment: If you know what the JPA API is, and what a JPA provider is, then you know that the API is the same! and that each provider adds their own way of doing things. You know what an interface is, and what an implementation of that interface is ? Basic java ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks same because they adhere to the specification but underlying architecture varies. So the performance of each solution would be different. 
If you and I develop a function to sort the data. A user would just call sort() function but the performance will vary.

See following: https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-performance-optimization to see the variation in their performance.

As Hibernate and EclipseLink provide additional features that are not part of the specification. BTW  before finalizing a 3rd party software, most of the companies run some experiments and compare results. They actually check the pros and cons of different solutions and choose one which suits their need.